# Hiding command-line dialog in py2exe

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe

Hi When I compile my python script with py2exe, everything works well except a usless command-line dialog appears as well as my GUI. Any way to fix this? I have python 2.7 and my setup script looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['Main.py'])
```

Please help!

Answer (score 14):

Using `setup(windows=['Main.py'])` should remove the command line dialog and use Main.py as your console, instead.

Comment: So my code should look like this:
`from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(windows=['Main.py'],console=['Main.py'])`

Comment: Still not working even with `windows=['Main.py']` please help

Comment: By it's not working do you mean that you still see the console window?

Comment: I haven't really used py2exe before, but if you still see the console window after using `windows=` instead of `console=` then maybe it's because there are errors redirected to `stdout` see [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/GuiApps) for more info.

Comment: No I just don't see anything, Is it because in main.py I don't use tk.mainloop()?

Comment: It was because i didn't use root.mainloop().

Answer (score 4):

Rename your entry point python script extension from `.py` to `.pyw` and regenerate your exe.

Example: `python -m py2exe.build_exe -b 0 my_script.pyw`

(tested with Python 3.4.3 on Windows 8.1 x64)

Example: `my_script.pyw`

```
import ctypes
MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
MessageBox(None, 'Hello', 'Hello Window Title', 0)
```

You should not see a command prompt for this GUI application.