# Executable python program - disable cmd line?

Tags: python, user-interface, cmd, executable, py2exe

I have a simple GUI python 2.7 app developed with wxpython. I don't want it to show the cmd line. I renamed the file to *.pyw and when I open it as a python script it works ok (no cmd line). But when I compile it via py2exe, the executable file shows the cmd line anyways. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding command-line dialog in py2exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003040/hiding-command-line-dialog-in-py2exe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `window` instead of `console` in your setup script.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(window=['hello.py'])
```

Comment: it should be: setup(windows=['hello.py']) (not 'window')

Answer (score 2):

OK, sorry for the trouble, a bit more research and I found the answer here:

[Hiding command-line dialog in py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003040/hiding-command-line-dialog-in-py2exe)

Anyways thank you for your time.