# How to run a python program in the background?

Tags: python, python-2.7, console, py2exe

How can I make a python program run in the background?
I don't need the console running since all it does is sends me emails with updates once an hour.
Is there a way to do it when I convert it to exe using py2exe?
 I am using python 2.7.8. 
Also, is there a way to make it open in the boot menu immediately when the computer turns on from the code?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking strictly how to hide the console as part of the py2exe bundling, that's simple. See - [Hiding command-line dialog in py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003040/hiding-command-line-dialog-in-py2exe)

If you are asking how to have a program without a GUI, just build the program in py2exe as above and run it. Unless you have created a GUI, it will run on it's own until it terminates or is terminated.

Comment: From what I understood, he wants a python daemon to run in the background, without having to have a console window being open. He also wants to know if he can set the program to run on startup.

Comment: @bspymaster, you're correct. Related question with multiple solutions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/is-it-possible-to-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-if-possible-how